# Getting build-args to docker.... from skaffold

Tags: skaffold

I am using skaffold to deploy a developer-instance of a service into a local cluster, and one of the Dockerfile's uses a deploy-token to grab code from a local repo.

```
FROM something
ARG DEPLOY_TOKEN
ARG DEPLOY_SECRET

## stuff

RUN git clone https://${DEPLOY_TOKEN}:${DEPLOY_SECRET}@gitlab.example.com/myGroup/funky_plugin local/path

## more stuff
```

This is known, and I can use `.env` to feed a `docker-compose.yml` file, and gitlab CI/CD variables to feed a CI/CD build process :thumbs up:

In my skaffold.yaml file, I then match this with:

```
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: registry.gitlab.example.com/myGroup/awesome_app
    context: ../awesome_app
    docker:
      buildArgs:
        STACK_TOKEN: "{{.DEPLOY_TOKEN}}"
        STACK_SECRET: "{{.DEPLOY_SECRET}}"
```

My understanding (from reading https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/env-file/) is that I can define these variables in `skaffold.env` (in the same dir as `skaffold.yaml`), and they will be picked up as environment variables - eg:

```
DEPLOY_TOKEN=abc
DEPLOY_SECRET=123
```

..... that's not happening

If I actually `export DEPLOY_TOKEN=abc` & `export DEPLOY_SECRET=123`... then it works.

1. Am I correct in understanding of what `skaffold.env` does?
2. How do I actually do this?